# Basic Combinations and Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider a team of eleven (11) soccer players, all of whom are equally good players and can play any position.

A) The coach wants to form two (2) teams of five (5) from the eleven players on the team for a scrimmage game (i.e., just a small practice game where player positions are not important). The eleventh player will act as the referee. How many ways can the coach divide the team into two teams of five players?

B) The coach wants to test the players to be able to select a captain for the team. Therefore, again the coach wants to form two (2) teams of five (5) from the eleven players on the team for a scrimmage game, with the eleventh player again acting as the referee, but with a small change. The first person chosen for a team of five will be the captain of the team and will have extra responsibilities. For the rest of the players, their roles and positions are not important. How many ways can the coach divide the team into two teams of five players with one captain for each team?

Comment: The answer for $A$) is $$\frac{11!}{5!\cdot 5!\cdot 1!}=\frac{11!}{5!\cdot 5!}=2772$$ ways

Comment: For $B)$ it should be $$25\cdot 2772=69300$$ ways

Comment: @Peter I disagree.  Technically there is no mention of whether the two teams are at all distinguishable but I would had made the assumption that they are not.  I.e. (12345)(6789T)(0) would be the same arrangement to me as (6789T)(12345)(0).  As such, you would have doublecounted.

Comment: @Peter I got the same answers but as Jmoravitz said, the fact that the players are seperated into two teams makes me unsure of my answers

Comment: @JMoravitz OK, here it should be the same arrangement, so we have to divide by $2$

Comment: @Peter a *division* by two you mean.  Your answer of $\frac{11!}{5!5!1!}$ counts the number of ways to choose five people for team $A$, five additional people for team $B$, and one person for the referee spot.  You need to "forget" which team was $A$ and which was $B$.  An alternate explanation that avoids "division by symmetry" would be:  pick who the referee is ($11$ ways).  Among the ten people leftover, one will be the youngest.  Pick who the four people on the youngest players team is ($\binom{9}{4}$ ways), giving $11\cdot\binom{9}{4}=1386$ ways.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: @JMoravitz does the same logic apply to question B)? Since technically, both teams are composed of 1 permutation (captain) and 4 combinations (players)? Thank you all for your help by the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Pick who the referee is in $11$ ways.  Then among the ten people leftover, one will be the youngest.  Pick who the other four members of that player's team is in $\binom{9}{4}$ ways.  We get a total of $11\binom{9}{4}=1386$ ways.

b) Pick who the referee is in $11$ ways.  Simultaneously pick the two captains in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways.  Pick who the other four members of the youngest captain's team is in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways.  We get a total of $11\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{4}=34650$ ways.

---

Alternate approach:

a) Arrange five a's, five b's, and a c in a line in $\frac{11!}{5!5!1!}$ ways.  Have the players go to either team $A$, team $B$, or referee position according to the arrangement of the a's, b's, and c's compared to their names.  Now, "forget" which team was actually team $A$ and which team was team $B$ by dividing by two.  This gives us $\frac{11!}{5!5!1!}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=1386$ ways.

b) Arrange four a's, four b's, one A, one B, and one C in a line in $\frac{11!}{4!4!1!1!1!}$ ways.  The a's will correspond to which players are normal members of team $A$, the A will correspond to the player who is captain for team $A$ etc... Finally, "forget" which team was actually team $A$ and which was team $B$ by dividing by two.  This gives us $\frac{11!}{4!4!1!1!1!}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=34650$ ways.

Similarly, one could instead just take the answer to part (a) and then pick who from the youngest person's team is captain and pick who the captain is for the other team, making it so there is $5\cdot5\cdot1386=34650$ ways.

Comment: can you please explain why for part A you multiple by 1/2? I'm not sure I fully understand what do you mean by: " Now, "forget" which team was actually team AA and which team was team B"

Comment: @adhg The "shepherd's principle" states that to count the number of sheep in a field (*where there are only sheep and all sheep have four legs*) we may instead count the number of legs and divide by four.  In the same way here, we recognize that we have counted every outcome exactly twice (once where the youngest playing player was on team $A$ and again when the youngest playing player was on team $B$ but otherwise the same people are arranged with the same people on eachother's teams).  We can "divide by symmetry" here to account for the overcounting, in this case by dividing by two.

Comment: @adhg since many people don't like division by symmetry arguments, it is often preferable to come up with arguments that avoid division all-together.  See my first solution for one such method.  (*Division by symmetry arguments are often used as well in proving the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, but you can avoid division arguments when proving that as well.  See the wiki article*)